# Using categorical predictive distribution to predict an outcome

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, mixture-distribution

I'm a bit new to Bayesian statistics and probability theory in general, but I've been trying my hand at a quick utilization of it of where there are 26 outcomes and I am trying to predict the next outcome.

As usual, I gave my mixtures a Dirichlet prior distribution and my distributions for the mixtures are Categorical Distributions of 1-of-26. With this, I observe some observations $$\textbf{X} = \{ x_1 = 0, x_2 = 15, x_3 = 22, ..... x_N\}$$
And then I try to use the predictive distribution. The problem is, I am almost certain I am using it incorrectly. My current method is this:

1. Compute the conditional probabilities for each mixture. This gives
   $K$ probabilities that "should" sum to 1.
2. Sample from this distribution $K$ vector as if it were a categorical distribution to pick some mixture $k$.
3. Sample from the $k$ mixture model (using its
   respective categorical distribution).

For step 1 - I compute for each $K$ mixture models, the following probability:
$$p(z = k|X) = p(z)\cdot\underbrace{\Pi_{i=1}^Np(x_i|z)}_{\text{Each observation}}$$
The problem is that...for Step 1, I get extremely small  numbers. Even when I use log probabilities, I have to eventually renormalize them and this yields very unstable computations. Most of the time, only one mixture will survive and all the others will die out. (So $p(z = k|X) \approx 1$ for some k mixture model). This leads me to believe that my procedure is incorrect. Could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Is your step 1 supposed to be [naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)? (That would be a $\times$ instead of a $+$, and would have a normalization factor as well.)

Comment: The likelihood is a function of parameters and not a probability distribution.  It is unclear what you mean when you call it a distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that my prior distribution is Dirichlet, and my distribution for the actual mixtures are categorical. By likelihood distribution, I mean given some mixture $k$, what is the distribution for the 26 outcomes dictated by this mixture?

Comment: @GeoMatt22, reading the page of naive Bayes, is that not what I am doing? (If I'm not mistaken). I renormalize the probabilities afterwards as well

Comment: Bayes would be $p(z|X)=p(X|z)p(z)/p(X)$, notice that $p(z)$ is $\times$ rather than $+$, and that there is a normalization factor $p(X)$ (= sum of numerator over  possible $z$'s). Naive Bayes is just asssuming the $x_i$ are conditionally independent given $z$, so $p(X|z)$ can be expanded into the product you give.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. the plus is there due to log probabilities that I forgot to show. I'll try to use the appropiate normalization constant instead of normalizing the vector afterwards